# Conformal dimension of conserved current of WZW model

Tags: conformal-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, wess-zumino-witten

The holomorphic part of the conserved current of a Wess-Zumino-Witten model is given by
$ J = - k \partial g g ^ { - 1 } $, where $ g $ is a map from $ S^ 2 $ to some Lie group.
It is claimed that this current has conformal weight 1,
I was just wondering if anyone had a method to prove this, since I don't know how to work
with maps into a Lie group.

Comment: Conserved currents in CFT in $d$ dimensions always have scaling dimension $d-1$, so in 2d it is $1$. This is covered in most texts on CFTs.